# Start service with Docker container & prevent container from quitting immediately

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

When my Ubuntu Docker container is started, I want SSH server to be running and the container should not quit immediately until I run `docker stop $container_id`

Is there any difference between these 3 `ENTRYPOINT`? Is there a better way to do it?

```
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && bash
```

```
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && tail -f /dev/null
```

```
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && sleep infinity
```

Comment: This might help: https://dev.to/s1ntaxe770r/how-to-setup-ssh-within-a-docker-container-i5i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, best entrypoint for a SSH container would be:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-eD"]
```

- `-D`: to make it daemon mode(running in the background but using tty)
- `-e`: log to stderr instead of log file. this way You can check ssh logs with `docker logs <containerName>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also  start the `ssh daemon` to run in the background
here is an example:

```
RUN service ssh start 
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

this will start the ssh daemon in the container in a background mode

Comment: You can't use `RUN` to start a background process; it won't be persisted in the image.  `RUN service ... start` does nothing and you can delete that line.